# How reverse dns record (PTR) should be?

Tags: reverse-dns, pointers

My mails send to junk mail by hotmail. I've no reverse dns record and I want to add it. I use direct admin and I add a new zone. But I couldn't understand what is the true result? When I check ptr record with ip what should be the result? mail.domain.com or domain.com?

And I wait your suggestions about hotmail mail problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I understood the questions as this:

You have a domain and the emails you send from your domain goes go Hotmail Spam filter.

provided that you are not sending spam ;) this should help:

1. Find out if you are blacklisted
2. find out what IP you are using (and make sure it is not dynamic)
3. Find out where you got the IP address from (use ripe.net - NOT .org)
4. Convince your IP maintainer to setup PTR record to the hostname of your email server.
5. check that it is done correctly, and wait 24-48 hours (add 24-48 hours to the TTL of the arpa zone).

When Hotmail mail servers now receive your emails they will look up the reverse IP to check if the hostname match the hostname your Email server ID itself as.

This means if your mailserver: chad.domain.tld [127.0.0.1] is setup to identify itself as Chad [127.0.0.1] the reverse lookup will find: 0.0.127.in-addr.arpa ptr chad.domain.tld

Background:
PTR records are setup in the arpa zonefile of your IP address

Your mailserver IP : 127.127.1.1